# Is VSS 2008 free?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe

In my company we use Visual Studio 2008. Is VSS 2008 free?

Comment: VSS = Visual Source Safe ? I certainly hope, it is free.

Comment: @driis: OTOH, if it's free, it might lure innocent people into using it...

Comment: @driis - Check your facts. It is **not** free.

Comment: @Oded, it was meant as a joke. Perhaps I should have added a smiley ;-) The point being that there are so many better alternatives than VSS, VSS development has been discontinued and support for it is to be discontinued soon. So paying for it would be a bad idea. Of course that does not mean that it is free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, there is no VSS 2008. There is VSS 2005.

Second, it comes with certain versions of Visual Studio.

From [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/richardb/archive/2007/12/03/vs-2008-and-sourcesafe-q-a.aspx) blog entry:

> There is no VSS 2008

and

> Q: Where do I get VSS2005 anyway?
>
> A: If you have a Team Edition of Visual Studio 2005 or later, then VSS2005 is included in your license.  It was included on the VSTS 2005 set of discs; you can also download it from MSDN.  If you have a Professional Edition of Visual Studio or lower then you need to purchase VSS separately.

Answer (score 8):

The last version of Visual Source Safe was VSS 2005.

I'm not sure if it has been released free or not...but even if it was, I'd suggest you stear clear. There are plenty of Open Source alternatives with good Visual Studio Integration.

You could try Subversion (server based), Git (distributed), or Mercurial (distributed).

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe):

> The final version of the product,
>   Visual SourceSafe 2005, is retired
>   from mainstream support on 12 April
>   2011 with extended support ending on
>   12 April 2016.

There is no VSS 2008.